# Execute git bash from gradle task

Tags: gradle, git-bash

I have a bash script that needs to be execute as a part of a task. This script works fine on its own from git bash, yet I can't get gradle to run git bash and execute the script.

I've tried something like this:

```
task example(type:Exec) {
    workingDir '.'
    executable 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe'
    args './path/to/script.bash'
}
```

I even tried something simpler, like `pwd` or a simple `echo`

Is there any way to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look here?
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html
I suppose you're specifying parameters in a wrong way.

For Mac you can do it easily:

```
task example(type:Exec) {
    workingDir '.'
    commandLine './echo_example.sh'
}
```

For windows just specify commands in commandLine according to the documentation above.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you get it correct at command line first, then try in Gradle. From a DOS prompt (not git bash) does the following work?

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" ./path/to/script.bash
```

If that fails, it'll obviously fail in Gradle too

Comment: I have already tried running that from windows cmd and it worked, it also seems to work fine on a brand new project, I guess there's something wrong with my real project's configuration that breaks it. Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work like this. It launches the git-bash shell anyway!

```
exec {
     commandLine '"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe"'
     args  '-i --cd=." ./encryptkey.sh'
     standardOutput = encryptedKeyStdOut
     standardInput = keyStdIn
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use commandline executions with scripts is the way like the gradle documentation says.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html

```
// Windows Way --> Use ',' for executable params
// ('--login' will make sure that profile and so on is loaded correctly so that all commands are available)
commandLine '"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"', '--login'
args './script.sh'

// Unix Way... (Just use the script)
commandLine './script.sh'
```

You could then combine it:

```
if (System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
    // Use git bash on windows...
    commandLine '"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"', '--login'
    args './script.sh'
} else {
    // UNIX Style Operating Systems
    commandLine './script.sh'
}
```

But this is in general not a very good solution I guess...
It would be better to have a Plugin which tries to achieve the task from the Script in a general OS independent way.
But to get it working for multiple OS in the first place it can be used as a starting point.